# subscripts in plot axis labels

Tags: plotting, text

Superscripts can be included in axis labels by the use of the caret symbol (e.g., `Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, x^2}]`).

How does one include subscripts in an axis label? The use of the underscore character does not seem to work (e.g., `Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, f_i(x)}]`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a subtle problem if you use strings as axis labels. Look closely at a plot like this:

```
Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(i\)]\)(x)"}]
```

You will see that the argument `x` in the function appears in a *different* font style than the argument on the horizontal axis.

To make sure that you get a consistent font style on both axes using the default styling for graphics, you should use the following:

```
Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[Subscript[f, i][x]]}]
```

Of course, to enter the `Subscript` expression in your label, you can still use the keyboard shortcuts that are mentioned by @Szabolcs.

The argument in `HoldForm` is your vertical label, typed in actual Mathematica syntax with square brackets for the function argument. I didn't surround the horizontal label in `HoldForm`, but you could do that for safety, in particular if your variable `x` has been assigned a value somewhere else in the Notebook.

Comment: Thanks, that ensures consistent typesetting of the axis labels. In my case, variables in the axis labels remain italicized.

Comment: Yes, it's TraditionalForm.

Answer (score 6):

Enclose the label in quotation marks for safety (just in case any symbols you use in them are defined), and enter two-dimensional input.  [Check the documentation on how to do it.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput.html)  You can enter a subscript using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>.  The Basic Math Assistant palette can be useful as well---it has a Typesetting section.

Comment: oooh, how do you do the nice `CTRL` commands?

Comment: @tkott Click the edit link to see ;-)  It was really useful here because CTRL-- isn't very clear...  Maybe CTRL-[-]

Comment: *smacks head* thanks :)

Comment: Despite the fact than I ran out of votes hours ago I *keep trying to vote*.  It's become a habit.

Comment: Thanks. When I enclose the label in quotation marks, it romanizes the text. Can I force it to remain italic? If I try `LabelStyle->{Italic}`, the tick labels are italicized in addition to the axis labels. I prefer for the axis labels to be italic and the tick labels to be roman.

Comment: @user001 I usually just select it and press Ctrl-I.  If you have a subscript, there's no need for that.  I'm open to hearing better suggestions, as I use this often too.

Comment: Hmm, my plot shows the f and i as italic, and only the (x) part as not-italic

Answer (score 3):

That's because `_` is only a subscript in LaTeX world. In MMA, you can simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. The following should show you what I mean (once you copy it into MMA):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(i\)]\)[x]"}]
```

Note that the reason that `x^2` shows up like it does is because `^2` is automatically changed to MMA's boxes / display format. If you were to write:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, "x^2"}]
```

You'll notice the caret stick around.

Comment: Thanks, I erroneously tend to assume I can transplant LaTeX practices to Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create the label with strings:

```
Plot[f, {x, -1, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {x, 
   Style[Row[{Subscript["f", "i"], "(x)"}], FontFamily -> "Times", 12,
     Italic]}]
```

Comment: This works fine in most simply labels, but it quickly gets ugly when you have actual Mathematica expressions as labels. Just replace the vertical label by Sin[x] and ask how you'd format that in a string so that it doesn't come out as _sin(x)_ but sin(_x_). This is just a simple example - the point is that it's much better to let the default `TraditionalForm` in plot labels do the work for you.

Comment: I agree @Jens but the question related to a simple subscript.