# Using a function name instead of its definition in AxesLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling

I seek to use a token as an axis label, but this token, having other meanings, is expanded by Mathematica. If I enclose the token in quotes, it is not expanded, but it is also no longer italicized. Using `LabelStyle->{Italics}` results in italicization of all fonts in the figure (axis labels and axis tick labels). How do I circumvent token expansion (or equivalently, in effect, italicize only the axis labels and not the axis tick labels)?

Two examples:

(1) I may wish to plot a function `f` (say `f=x^2`) and want the axis label to be simply `f` (in italics), but it is expanded to `x^2` by the command `Plot[f, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}]`. Changing to `Plot[f, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, "f"}]` results in italic `x` and roman `f`.

(2) I may wish to label an axis with `E`, but it is changed by Mathematica to `e` (the irrational constant). Again, I can use `"E"`, but this has the undesired effect of altering the font face.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for can be achieved by wrapping the labels in `HoldForm`, or if you prefer, `HoldForm@InputForm`. For example, here is a plot that combines both labeling issues you mentioned:

```
f = x^2;
Plot[f, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[InputForm[E = f]]}]
```

The two issues you mention are indeed separate:

1. To get `f` instead of $x^2$ you should use `HoldForm`, but that still allows the display of `TraditionalForm` shorthand forms for built-in symbols such as `E` (which is Euler's constant but is pretty-printed as $\mathbb e$).
2. To prevent the replacement of `E` by $\mathbb e$, `InputForm` can be used.

As you noticed, using strings in labels (though sometimes perfectly fine) has undesirable effects on the font and requires more "finger-painting" with styles. The `HoldForm` approach is easier to use and the code is easier to read when labels get complicated.

See also [this related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/subscripts-in-plot-axis-labels)

**To expand on this topic:**

Sometimes you need more complicated labels that require "two-dimensional" typesetting, as in $\psi = \frac{1}{2}\int f(x) \mathbb{d}x$, see this image:

[image: formulas in labels]

**Edit: how to get formatting into labels in general**

For output like the above, the essential ingredient is that the expression should be wrapped in a `FormBox`. Strings aren't made for two-dimensional display, but Mathematica has a way of sneaking `FormBox`es into strings: [see the documentation.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html)

Therefore, you can get a two-dimensional formula into a plot label *either* using `HoldForm` or a string. Using `HoldForm`, I got the formatting in the image by doing the following:

1. Create the formula in a `TraditionalForm` environment. This could e.g. be in a Text cell by starting an equation with `Ctrl-(` and ending with `Ctrl-)`.
2. Copy this formula from *within* that math inset.
3. Lay out your plot by typing something like `Plot[f, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[    ]}]`
4. In the blank space that I have left inside the `HoldForm[    ]`, paste the copied equation.
5. You will be asked if you want to wrap the `TraditionalForm` expression in a `FormBox`, and the answer is *yes*.
6. Provided that the pasted expression obeys Mathematica syntax, you should now be able to evaluate the plot cell and get the output shown above.

Now in some cases you want to label a graph with a two-dimensional formula that *doesn't* obey Mathematica syntax, and in that case you would replace step 4. above by this:

```
Plot[f, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x,""}
```

Instead of `HoldForm`, I now left an empty *string* `""` in the label. Now proceed as above with step 4, for example using an equation like

```
-(\[HBar]^2/(2m))\[PartialD]^2 \[Psi]
```

entered in a math inset (in a text cell as in step 1). If you tried this with `HoldForm`, it would give a syntax error because the `\[PartialD]` is being used in a mathematically acceptable but syntactically incorrect way.

**Edit 2: the fastest way**

The way I described copying and pasting of `TraditionalForm` into strings was based on my habits, but it's actually not the fastest. I should adjust my habits to the following: In the code for your plot, type a single string placeholder letter for your label, such as `"y"`. Using the mouse, highlight the `y` in your string and go to the menu item `Cell > Convert To > TraditionalForm` (or use the keyboard shortcut). This creates the all-important `FormBox`. Since this box is invisible, you now have to use the arrow keys or mouse to get inside this `FormBox`, right next to to the placeholder `y`. From here, you can start typing any arbitrary formula which will then be typeset as `TraditionalForm` in the plot label.

So in conclusion, `HoldForm` is a very direct way of getting valid Mathematica expressions into labels without expanding them, and strings should be used in combination with the `FormBox` wrapper method above to typeset arbitrarily complicated labels.

Comment: Thanks Jens. Is `HoldForm@InputForm` the same as `HoldForm[InputForm[...]]`?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: @Jens, I was trying to reproduce what you did and I realized that it does not work in Mathematica 10 but it does in Mathematica 9. Similarly, `Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Text[TraditionalForm[x]], 
 Epilog -> Text[x, {3, 1}]]` puts both x's in TraditionalForm in version 9 but not in version 10. Is this supposed to be the case? Is there another work around?

Comment: @BenAllgeier I also see this problem, and I think it's a bug in version 10. I'm currently mostly using version 8 because I want to wait until the bugs are fixed. In the meantime, maybe you can instead use my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6165/245), until we figure out what's wrong with `HoldForm`. I'll update this when I know more...

Comment: @Jens, I could not get it to work in version 10. I am not sure I mastered your technique from your other posts. How did you get   `\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)]\)/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i\)]\) == \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[
SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)], 
SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i\)]])\) p)\)\)/n

Magnify[%] // TraditionalForm`  from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/formula-formatting-is-small-and-chunky/6165#6165)

Comment: @Jens, I think I figured out how you were getting that. I guess when you paste it into the comments that is what it looks like. Anyway, I can get your technique to work in version 9 but I could not get it to work in version 10. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use strings for the labels and `Style` them as you like — change colour/font/fontsize, etc. For example:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Italic, Red, FontFamily -> "Verdana"] & /@ {"x","sinc(x)"})]
```

This will style only the labels and leave the tick marks intact.

[image]

Comment: Thanks R.M. A question about the syntax. The `#`, `&` seems to be a cooptation of the pure function syntax, whereby the `{"x","sinc(x)"}` are substituted into the `#`. How about the `/@`? This suggests to me an effect similar to `/. # -> {"x","sinc(x)"}`, but I'm not familiar with `/@` per se.

Comment: @user001 `/@` is shorthand for [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), which applies a function to each element in the list (loosely speaking). Strictly speaking, it applies to every element in the first level of the expression (doesn't necessarily have to be a list). See the linked documentation for more :)

Comment: @R.M I noticed you left out the quotation marks around the Verdana font name. It needs to be "Verdana", otherwise it's not recognized and you get Helvetica.

Comment: @Jens Oops! Thanks for catching that.