# Inline cells and conversion rules

Tags: front-end, conversion

In the following [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HTML.html) you can find the following about `ConversionRules` when exporting to HTML:

> specifies mappings from Mathematica cell styles to HTML elements, including both inline and block-level versions of the markup

Lets define the following temporary function with the following conversion rules:

```
TempFunction[expr_] := ExportString[expr, "HTML",
    "FullDocument" -> False,
    "ConversionRules" -> {
        "InlineMath" -> {
            {"<inline>", Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[#] &, "</inline>"},
            {"<block>", Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[#] &, "</block>"}
        },
        "Text" -> {
            {"<inlineText>", "</inlineText>"},
            {"<blockText>", "</BlockText>"}
        },
        "" -> {"", ""}
    }
]
```

As the quote says, I have specified both the inline and block versions of the mapping. Now lets use it to see if they work as intended.

## CASE 1:

Here we use a single block cell.

```
TempFunction[
    Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"x", "=", "y"}], TraditionalForm]], "InlineMath"]
]
```

The output is:

```
<block>x=y</block>
```

## CASE 2:

Here we use an inline cell.

```
TempFunction[
    Cell[TextData[{"Let ", 
    Cell[BoxData[
    FormBox[RowBox[{"x", " ", "=", " ", SuperscriptBox["y", "2"]}],
    TraditionalForm]], "InlineMath", FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], "."}], "Text"]
]
```

```
<blockText>Let <inline>x = y^2</inline>.</BlockText>
```

## CASE 3:

```
TempFunction[
    Cell[TextData[{"Let ", 
    Cell[BoxData[
    FormBox[RowBox[{"x", " ", "=", " ", "y"}], TraditionalForm]], 
    "InlineMath", FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"], "."}], "Text"]
]
```

```
<blockText>Let <inline><em>x</em><em> </em><em>=</em><em> </em><em>y</em></inline>.</BlockText>
```

I was expecting this:

```
<blockText>Let <inline>x = y</inline>.</BlockText>
```

Is this a bug? What style is being surrounded by the tag em? Case 1 and Case 2 make sense, but Case 3 has me scratching my head. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Weird behaviour, that just by adding a superscriptbox in a rowbox, single letters are emphasized

Comment: @Rojo methink it is the other way around ...

Comment: @belisarius and Rojo, Since you guys are checking this out, try replacing TraditionalForm for TextForm in CASE 3. What do you guys think?

Comment: @belisarious, I was being ironic, I meant the opposite, couldn't you tell?

Comment: @jmlopez, you mean that the problem gets fixed? Same happens with StandardForm. Probably has to do with TraditionalForm having SingleLetterItalics set to true. Can't test much right now

Comment: @Rojo, The problem does get fixed. But I just don't know why or how. Yes, I also tried it with StandardForm but I ended up choosing the other.

Comment: @jmlopez, I have no clue why adding a SuperscripbBox in the RowBox could ever make such a difference. You want single letters to be emphasised or not? Perhaps you could test editing the style "TraditionalForm" in the stylesheet and setting SingleLetterItalics to False then?

Comment: @Rojo, I think this might be due to how the HTML conversion works. If you change the second argument of `ExportString` from "HTML" to "TeX" then it works as I expected. In any case, I do not want the letters to be emphasized. For now the quick solution is to not to use TraditionalForm.

Comment: @Rojo Nope. It was "too late for tears" here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to turn this off globally for your current kernel session by using a variant of the [solution posted by Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5500/8) to an earlier question of mine:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 FormatType :> (Style[TraditionalForm[##],SingleLetterItalics -> False] &)]
```

You might also want to set the same for `Graphics`, depending on what you are exporting.

```
SetOptions[Graphics,
 FormatType :> (Style[TraditionalForm[##],SingleLetterItalics -> False] &)]
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, at least with the example that I showed. Still, +1, for showing me that you can modify different parts of a style. For now, the best answer I have is set `DefaultInlineFormatType->TextForm`, in the notebook options. That way, when you write inline cells, in this case, my `InlineMath` cell, then it will have the `TextForm` as default and the HTML converter will not emphasize the letters.