# Annotating plots with plain (not italicized) mathematical text

Tags: plotting, formatting

I have a plot and I would like to annotate some mathematical text in it. Initially, Mathematica puts it in italics by using Drawing tools palette, but I want it all in plain text. How can I do it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have a look at `Epilog`, `Text[]`, and possibly `Style[]`.

Comment: You will find a list of closely related posts near the bottom of my answer to ["Create complicated text formulas in graphics"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7005/245)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Drawing tools and annotate by hand, the palette offers standard format options out of the box. Just choose your font, font size etc.:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As Verbeia says, that solution will fail if I want to re-evaluate my plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yves' answer is perfect if you are never going to re-evaluate your plot, for example because the data have been updated. Annotations drawn with the drawing tools are not part of the plot definition code and so are not included if you re-evaluate it.

It is not 100% clear from your question, but I think you are being stung by the same thing I was: typeset mathematical expressions italicize in ways you might not want.

See if the accepted answer [to my earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5493/8) solves your problem.

By default Mathematica typesets mathematical expressions inside a `Text` expression. It does not italicize standard function names like $\sin$, but it does for single-letter symbols. Notice that I have placed the text using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html). It is a good function to get to know, along with [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html) and [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html).

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Sin[x], {5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image]

If you want to turn off the italicization of $x$, then use the `FormatType` option as described in Albert's answer to my question linked above.

Comment: Ok, it seem useful. Thanks.