# Mathematica italicizes single characters in text cells

Tags: output-formatting, properties

My Mathematica (v. 10.2) insists on italicizing single characters in text cells, including title cells, section cells, etc.  See the "a" in "Define a rotation..." below for an example,

[image: text cell]

I've changed the notebook stylesheet (to the Mathematica Journal stylesheet) to no avail.  Selecting the cell and clearing the formatting using the Classroom Assistant palette changes nothing. I'm really stumped.  How do I stop Mathematica from doing this?

Edit: I found that using the button on the Classroom Assistant palette to generate a text cell gives one that behaves as I want.  Here’s an example:

```
Cell["hello", "Text"]
```

But using the `Alt-7` key shortcut makes a text cell like this

```
Cell[BoxData[ FormBox["hello", TraditionalForm]], "Text"]
```

which is the kind of cell that creates the problem.

Is there a way to change the `Alt-7` shortcut to insert a simple text cell, as above?

Comment: You have changed the Cell option value for [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics.html) to `False` and you still get this behavior?

Comment: Please show the sourcecode that led to the errant typeface.  Did you define `a` as a variable somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. Selecting the cell and right-clicking on "properties" brings up an "options inspector" dialog. Setting `SingleLetterItalics` to `False` in that dialog fixes the problem for that cell. Selecting "Global Preferences" in the Show option values dropdown shows `False`, but new cells still have the option set to `False`.  Is there a way to do this globally?

Comment: @David, I get `Cell[BoxData[ FormBox[ RowBox[{"Define", " ", "a", " ", "rotation"}], TraditionalForm]], "Text",...`.  `a` isn't defined anywhere else.  This behavior occurs anytime I type a single letter.

Comment: Why not... `"Define a rotation"` instead of `"Define", " ", "a", " ", "rotation"`?

Comment: @David. Don't know.  That's what typing in a text cell produces.  I don't know how to change it other than to edit the expression directly.

Comment: Will it suffice to set it for this notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Put `SingleLetterItalics->False` in a stylesheet inheriting from the default style sheet.  Then use an initialisation file (`init.m`) to load a startup notebook that sets your default style definitions.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,DefaultStyleDefinitions->"newStylesheet.nb"]
```

See also [How can I turn off SingleLetterItalics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6349/363)