# Way to input caligraphic letter as a axis label in Mathematica plot

Tags: fonts

In my paper written in LATEX, I used a symbol $\mathcal{T}$ and I want to put it in the axis label of my plot. 
However I could not find such functionality in Mathematica. Is it possible?

Comment: You can [specify any font](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24975/17) available on you OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find calligraphic script under the Palettes' Special Characters menu.  E.g.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {\[ScriptCapitalT], None}]
```

Or, if you specifically want the LaTeX Mathcal font - apparently [cmbsy10](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/download/extra-fonts/welcome.html) - you can download and install it, and specify it in the `Style` option:-

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {Style["T", FontFamily -> "cmbsy10"], None}]
```