# How do I control italicization of text in axes and frame labels?

Tags: output-formatting, text

How do I prevent my text from being italicized when I annotate it with additional glyphs?

For example if I add a "hat" to a variable, `z` as in $\widehat z$, but want `z` to not be italicized to match its use elsewhere:

```
Remove[z];
Plot[x^2, {x,-5,5},
  AxesLabel->{"P("<>ToString@StringForm["``",z]<>")",
              "Q("<>ToString@StringForm["Overscript[``, ^]",z]<>")"},
PlotTheme->"Classic"]
```

Conversely, how do I force `z` to be italic when it lacks an annotation (`ToString@Style[z,Italic]` doesn't do the trick)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/fixing-quirky-typesetting-in-plot-labels) has some more details for the first part of your question (i.e. how to prevent italic letters)

To get everything italic, simply specify everything as expression instead of as string:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {P[z], Q[OverHat[z]]}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To prevent italic letters, use [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics.html): (from the linked answer)

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> Thread@Style[{P[z], Q[OverHat[z]]}, SingleLetterItalics -> False], 
 PlotTheme -> "Classic"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That doesn't generalize well beyond the simple example. The expression I need is more along the lines of `P[b|X,Overscript[\[CapitalTheta], ^]\p]/P[Overscript[b, ^]| ...]`, which I have to build with a mess like `ToString[p],"P("<>ToString[p]<>"|X,Overscript[\[CapitalTheta], ^]\\" <> ToString[p]<> ") / P( "<>ToString@StringForm["Overscript[``, ^]",p]<>"|...)"`, which would be made yet worse if I wanted to fixe the italicized $\widehat b$.

Comment: I think I still don't fully understand your issue - for me, something like `P[b | X, OverHat@p]/P[OverHat@b | \[Ellipsis]] // TraditionalForm` looks like it should. And what do you want to achieve with your mix of `StringForm` and `ToString`? Does `p` have a value assigned? If so, what value?

Comment: Let me see if I can work up a more useful MWE (though the process may lead me back to Python; why are strings, and output in general, such a mess in MMA?).

Comment: OK, I think (after messing with this for too long) I see and just want to conform. Basically, to get anything interesting done, the idiom for each idem in `AxesLabel` or `FrameLabel` needs to be of the form `Style[Row@{...},options...]`. If that's about right then I think I got it.