# Manipulate a parameter within the PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, manipulate, labeling

Very similar to

[Parameters in plot titles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/parameters-in-plot-titles)

in which I want to call a parameter from an array using `PlotLabel` in my plot using `Manipulate`. I've tried all of the suggestions in the above post and keep getting the same error. Simple code:

```
f = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[f[[g]] x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> Text["f =" f[[g]]]], {g,
   1, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

Curiously, the first `f` value does not show up incorrectly to the left of the `"f="` string. Instead of `Text[]` I've also tried `HoldForm[]`, `TraditionalForm[]`, `Defer[]`. I'm not too picky on where `"f ="` shows up, but this is pretty confusing to me as why this doesn't work as it should. Thanks

Comment: `f = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[f[[g]] x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", f[[g]]}]],
 {{g, 1, "index"}, 1, Length[f], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]`

Answer (score 3):

What you observe is simply because you use a multiplication without noticing it. Basic example:

```
"f=" 2

(* 2 "f=" *)
```

If you look at the full form of this output with `FullForm[%]` you see that it is indeed `Times[2, "f="]`. Because the terms in a multiplication are re-ordered by Mathematica, you get the wrong result.

The solution is to either use `Row` like shown by Nasser in the comment

```
f = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; 
Manipulate[  
  Plot[Sin[f[[g]] x], {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", f[[g]]}]],  {{g, 1, "index"}, 1, 3, 1, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}  
]
```

or you create a full string from your content with

```
Text["f = " <> ToString[f[[g]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way using v10 `StringTemplate`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[f[[g]] x], {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> TemplateApply[s, g]], {g, Range[6]}, 
 Initialization :> (f = Range[6]; 
   s = StringTemplate["f=<*f[[`1`]]*>"])]
```

[image]

If you prefer the traditional form of expressions rather than the version in graphics one way (there are almost certainly better):

```
Manipulate[
 With[{lab = 
    Rasterize[TraditionalForm[TemplateApply[st, g] // DisplayForm], 
     RasterSize -> 100, ImageSize -> 50]}, 
  Plot[Sin[f[[g]] x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> lab]], {g, Range[6], 
  SetterBar}, 
 Initialization :> (f = Range[6]; 
   st = StringTemplate["f=<*f[[`1`]]*>", CombinerFunction -> RowBox])]
```

[image]