# TraditionalForm for PlotLabel with a parameter

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation

This is a simple variation/spin off of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/parameters-in-plot-titles), but I am having trouble. In the second example in the original question, I'm trying to get the $a=$ in the `PlotLabel` to be in `TraditonalForm` (with an italicized $a$ instead of a non-italic `a`).

```
testplot[a_] := Plot[a x^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLabel -> StringForm["a=`1`", a]]

testplot[2]
```

**Edit:** Here's my particular example of this issue in v10

```
   Table[ContourPlot[Norm[{x, y}, p] == 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Accuracy", ImageSize -> 250, 
   PlotLabel -> Text["p=" <> ToString@p, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]], 
   {p, {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 50, 500}}]
```

Comment: Even if you are taking code from an other question you should provide some code here.

Comment: I also suggest that you formulate here your question completely

Comment: `PlotLabel -> Text["a=" <> ToString@a, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]`?

Comment: @Öskå doesn't work

Comment: It works pretty fine for me. I don't know what else you are expecting then.

Comment: `Table[ContourPlot[
  Norm[{x, y}, p] == 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Accuracy", ImageSize -> 250, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Text["p=" <> ToString@p, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]], {p, {1, 
   2, 3, 4, 10, 50, 500}}]` formats the p= as plain text for me (v10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this accomplishes your goal:

```
Table[ContourPlot[
   Norm[{x, y}, p] == 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Accuracy", ImageSize -> 250, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{TraditionalForm[HoldForm[p]], "\[ThinSpace]=", p}]], 
   {p, {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 50, 500}}]
```

The `\[ThinSpace]` is included just to properly space before the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid strings and just use an expression (Mathematica by default formats labels in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm)):

```
Table[
    ContourPlot[
        Norm[{x,y},p]==1,
        {x,-1.2,1.2},
        {y,-1.2,1.2},
        PlotLabel->HoldForm[p]==p
    ],
    {p,{1,500}}
]
```

[image]

In comparison to the accepted answer, note that the labels use a long equal sign instead of a regular equal sign, and the spacing on either side of the equal sign is even.