# Labeling plots without evaluation

Tags: plotting, evaluation, output-formatting, labeling

This is my first question here so please excuse my mistakes.

Let us consider a rather contrived example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x y z
{y, z} = {1, 1};
Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> f[x, y, z]]
Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> Subscript[f, x, y, z]]
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> f[x, y, z]], {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Only `PlotLabel` is used here, but I am making the same argument for `AxesLabel`, `Epilog -> Inset[]`, and other ways of labeling plots. The problem here is that the evaluator in Mathematica eagerly replaces all occurrences of `f`, `y` and `z` by their values, so instead of $f(x,y,z)$ in the plot one sees $x$. There are several solutions:

1. Different variables, say `ff`, `yy` and `zz`, can be used in the code, leaving the symbols `f`, `y` and `z` free for labeling. However, this makes the code much more incomprehensible.
2. Labels can be enclosed in quotes, for example, `"f[x, y, z]"`. This works with `Subscript[f, x, y, z]` but the formatting is wrong for `f[x, y, z]` (variables are not italicized and brackets appear in lieu of parentheses).
3. Labels can be enclosed in `HoldForm` or `Block`, for example, `HoldForm[f[x, y, z]]` or `Block[{f, x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]]`. This does not work for `Manipulate`, presumably because it defines its own local variables.
4. Type such monstrosity as `\!\(\*FormBox[SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(x, y, z\)],
   TraditionalForm]\)` directly in the code.

I wonder if there is a simple way to tell Mathematica to use the expression `f[x,y,z]` as-is, with formatting but without evaluation. It would even be better if I can tell it to, say, replace only `y` with its current value in `Manipulate` but leave `z` untouched.

As an additional question, it is sometimes nice to label a condition on the plot, such as $y=1$. I can get away with

```
Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm[y] == y]
Clear[y]
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> Symbol["y"] == y], {y, 0, 
  1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

but this seems awfully complicated and inconsistent. Perhaps I can again tell Mathematica to skip evaluating `Equal`, and treat it as a given expression?

### Edit

Based on the discussion below I have summarized several ad-hoc strategies to deal with labels:

- Define a label via

  ```
  l = {HoldForm[x], HoldForm@f[x, y, z]}
  l = StringForm["Plot of ``", HoldForm[Subscript[f, x, y, z]]]
  l = HoldForm[y == #1 \[And] z == #2] &
  ```

  in global scope, before local variables creep in. These should be shielded against all global and local definitions of the variables. (The last label should be used as `PlotLabel -> l[y, z]`.)
- Wrap `Plot` or `Manipulate` with a `Module` and define local labels in the same way. For example,

  ```
  Module[{l = HoldForm@f[x, y, z]}, 
   Manipulate[
    Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> l], {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    Initialization :> (f[x_, y_, z_] := x y z)]]
  ```

  This is okay as long as the label is defined outside of the scope in which `f`, `y` and `z` are actually used. But if the plotting code is to be encapsulated in a function `plot[f_] := ...`, then this approach fails if the label involves `f` and `f` is declared globally as a pure function, such as `f = #1 #2 #3 &`. In that case, one may consider `plot[fn_] := ...`.
- If `f` is to be displayed unevaluated, such as $f(x,y,0.12)$, use

  ```
  Manipulate[
   Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     With[{y = Symbol["y"], z = z}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]]], {y, 0, 
    1}, {z, 0, 1}, Initialization :> (f[x_, y_, z_] := x y z)]
  ```

  `y` is displayed as-is, and it is wrapped in `Symbol` so that it is properly formatted; but `y` must not already be defined globally, otherwise that global value will show. `z` shows its current value, set probably through a `Manipulate`.
- If `f` is to be displayed in evaluated form, such as $x\times y\times0.12$, use

  ```
  Manipulate[
   Plot[ReleaseHold@f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> With[{y = Symbol["y"], z = z}, f[x, y, z]]], {y, 0, 
    1}, {z, 0, 1}, Initialization :> (f[x_, y_, z_] := HoldForm[x y z])]
  ```

  However, it is hard to guarantee all plotting functions are wrapped in `HoldForm`.
- If any of the preserved variables (`x` and `y`) are already defined globally, it is possible to guard against them with `With[{x = "x", y = "y"}, ...]` at the cost of `x` and `y` not being properly formatted and the risk of wrong variable ordering.
- Nothing could be done if the variable is declared in the same scope as the label is used. `HoldForm[x]` will display its decorated name.

In short, there is no one single solution that works in every case except global-variable injection.

Comment: You can get it to replace (and update) inside the `Manipulate` using `Dynamic` as `PlotLabel -> HoldForm@f[x, Dynamic@y, Dynamic@z]`. I'm not sure how to not evaluate the `z` and not have it be ``FE`z$123`` other than the ways you've already mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)

Comment: Closely related: [Using a function name instead of its definition in AxesLabel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3290)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend not assigning values to `y` and `z` globally. I further recommend making your plot as follows:

```
f[x_,y_,z_] := x y z
Plot[f[x, 1, 1],{x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> HoldForm@f[x, 1, 1]]
```

I use the label `f[x,1,1]` because it more truly represents what you are plotting.

[image]

**Edit**

In the case where the `Plot` is evaluated inside a `Manipulate` expression, `HoldForm` can still be used, but must evaluated outside the `Manipulate`.

```
lbl = HoldForm@f[x, y, z];
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, y, z],{x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel->lbl],
   {y, 0, 1},
   {z, 0, 1},
   Initialization:>(f[x_, y_, z_] := x y z;)]
```

Comment: Global assignment is more an illustration than actual practice. Consider `Manipulate[Plot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> x y], {y, 0, 1}]`; here `y` is local but I still have a similar problem. I think whether the explicit appearance of the value of `y` is clearer depends on the subject matter at hand. Maybe for the sake of clarity I want to label the plot $y>0$ (or perhaps $y>z$, with the value of $z$ substituted in), but Mathematica usually gives me either `True` or `False` for a title.

Comment: Using `HoldForm` with `PlotLabel` is still the way to go.

Comment: As I noted in the question, `HoldForm` works except in `Manipulate`, in which case it gives me the decorated name of the local variable. Unfortunately I do need `Manipulate`. If one needs partial substitution, one needs to put a `HoldForm` around each preserved variable, which is not altogether elegant either.

Comment: @photon.engine Even in `Manipulate`, `HoldForm` is the way to go. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: I think @photon refers to the case when `f` is local to the `Manipulate`, e.g. is entered by the user in an `InputField`. There are some trobules...

Comment: @IstvánZachar. You may be right, but if that's the case, he put the questing rather obscurely.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Supposedly the solution from @m_goldberg can still be used in the form `l = HoldForm[f[x, y, z]]; Manipulate[Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> l], {f}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]`; the idea is to capture the variable before entering any scoping construct or function definition. (Of course, now we have a global variable for every label...) But I think the general spirit of my question is that it seems wasteful to give up a variable just so that it can be used to label things, and I want to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

A more general approach specifies the level of "*unevaluatedness*". If we have the function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
```

and we have some local values for `y` and `z` inside e.g. a `Manipulate`, there are at least 6 levels to keep `f` unevaluated:

- do not evaluate anything, and keep local symbol names: `` f[x, FE`y$$182, FE`z$$182] `` (or similar)
- do not evaluate anything: `f[x, y, z]`
- evaluate `y` and `z`: `f[x, 1, 3]`
- evaluate only `f`: `x + y + z`
- evaluate `f`, `y` and `z`: `x + 1 + 3`
- evaluate `f`, `y`, `z` and `Plus`: `4 + x`

Accordingly:

```
Manipulate[
 Column@{
   HoldForm@f[x, y, z],
   With[{y = "y", z = "z"}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]],
   With[{y = y, z = z}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]],
   With[{x = "x", y = "y", z = "z"}, f[x, y, z]],(* x must be specified, otherwise order would be: "y" + "z" + x  *)
   ReleaseHold@Block[{x, y, z}, Hold@f[x, y, z]],
   Framed@Plot[f[x, y, z], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> ReleaseHold@Block[{x, y, z}, Hold@f[x, y, z]]]
   },
 {y, 1, 2},
 {z, 3, 4},
 Initialization :> (f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that holding `Plus` from evaluation can only be done if the righthand side of the definition of `f` is wrapped in `Hold` or `HoldForm`, which requires some extra `ReleaseHold`, especially in the first argument of `Plot`:

```
Manipulate[
 Column@{
   HoldForm@f[x, y, z],
   With[{y = "y", z = "z"}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]],
   With[{y = y, z = z}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]],
   ReleaseHold@With[{x = "x", y = "y", z = "z"}, f[x, y, z]],
   f[x, y, z],
   ReleaseHold@f[x, y, z],
   Framed@Plot[ReleaseHold@f[x, y, z], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> f[x, y, z]]
   },
 {y, 1, 2},
 {z, 3, 4},
 Initialization :> (f[x_, y_, z_] := HoldForm[x + y + z])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(It's nice to know that `ReleaseHold` works on `HoldForm` too.)

Comment: I would improve on your solution by `With[{y = Symbol["y"], z = z}, HoldForm@f[x, y, z]]` and `With[{x = "x", y = Symbol["y"], z = z}, f[x, y, z]]}]`. The first one gives $f(x,y,0.12)$ whereas the second one gives $\mathrm{x}+y+0.12$. `x = "x"` guards against any globally defined value of `x`, but unfortunately prevents it from being formatted. It would be rather inconvenient to wrap all functions in `HoldForm` though.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood the question well. If this does not answer it, please let me know and will delete it.

But formating labels, titles, plot/graphics related labels and such, takes me long time to do it right and is not always easy. If you mean you want to format the label as `f(x,number,number)` , then using `Row[]` and manually format it is how I would do it,something like

```
Manipulate[
Plot[f[x,y,z],{x,-1,1},PlotLabel->Row[{Style["f",Italic],"(",x,",",y,",",z,")"}] ],
{y,0,1},
{z,0,1},
Initialization:>
(
f[x_,y_,z_]:=x y z;
)]
```

[image]

For you follow up question: `I wonder if there is a simple way to tell Mathematica to use the expression f[x,y,z] as-is, with formatting but without evaluation`

Again, I would do using `Row[]` like this

```
Manipulate[
Plot[f[x,y,z],{x,-1,1},PlotLabel->Row[{Style["f",Italic],
           "(",Style["x",Italic],",",Style["y",Italic],",",Style["z",Italic],")"}] ],
{y,0,1},
{z,0,1},
Initialization:>
(
f[x_,y_,z_]:=x y z;
)]
```

[image]

And at this time I do not yet understand your last question (the additional one). (May be you can post that as a separate question?).

Comment: Thanks! But the problem I have is that Mathematica is too quick at replacing my variables, whereas I would like my labels to stay as $f(x,y,z)$ which is clearer. You can see in my `Manipulate` example that both `y` and `z` show what their actual values are (instead of just $y$ and $z$). I do agree your second method works but it seems too much typing for something as simple as $f(x,y,z)$ ... maybe there is a general algorithm for generating such expressions? In addition, the second method seems to force the variables to be italic instead of using Mathematica's own formatting system.