# Using PlotLegends->"Expressions" inside Manipulate or DynamicModule doesn't work

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, legending, plotting

Take this simple example:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  {x^2 + y^2 <= c,
   x < 0},
  {x, -Pi, Pi},
  {y, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
  ],
 {{c, 3.}, 0., 10., 0.1}
 ]
```

As you can see (unless it's just me of course) the legend text does not display correctly. In particular the value of `c` is not substituted correctly when the legend text is evaluated.

Doing some research I found that Manipulate basically works like a DynamicModule, and indeed the following breaks in a very similar way, and I guess for the same reasons:

```
DynamicModule[{c = 3},
 RegionPlot[
  {x^2 + y^2 <= c,
   x < 0},
  {x, -Pi, Pi},
  {y, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
  ]
 ]
```

while using for example With instead of DynamicModule works correctly.

I could probably fix this by manually inserting the legend with something like

```
PlotLegends->"x^2+y^2<="<>c
```

but then I would have to manually tweak the font and all that.

*Why does this happen? And what is the correct way to deal with it?*

Comment: @Kuba where should I put that? If you mean it as replacement of "Expressions" it doesn't seem to work for me. The `x` is substituted with the value `4` and the `x<0` part is not shown.

Comment: `Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  Evaluate@{x^2 + y^2 <= c, x < 0}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {{c, 3.}, 0., 10., 0.1}]`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I saw similar quesition here.

Comment: @Kuba It did work after I evaluated a `ClearAll[x]`. It seems that with the `Evaluate` the Manipulate doesn't work unless `x`and `y` have not previous values, which makes sense given what `Evaluate` does. Unfortunately I cannot fix this other issue (or annoyance if you want) without wrapping it all into a `DynamicModule` or such, with which the previous issue returns.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want c as a symbol, sorry I missed this.

Comment: @Kuba not sure what you mean. In the legend text I want `c` to be substituted with the value currently given by the manipulate, which is correctly done with your solution. The problem with it is that if `x` or `y` have some previously assigned value that value is immediately substituted in the `Evaluate` and the plot is consequently broken. Wrapping the expression in a Module almost fixes this, except for the `x` being then written as `x$21438`.

Comment: Related: [(3290)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3290/121), [(13916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13916/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because legend items are wrapped in `HoldForm` to prevent the elements from taking on values:  Observe:

```
c = 5;

RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 <= c, x < 0}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"][[2, 1, 2]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {HoldForm[x^2 + y^2 <= c], HoldForm[x < 0]}
> ```

Without the `HoldForm` any global values (such as `c = 5`) would be substituted.  Most of the time that would be a *bad thing*.

To get the behavior you want you just need to replace `c` within the `RegionPlot` *before* it is evaluated.  This is the same problem as [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121) and the same methods can be used, e.g. the Accepted answer using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html):

```
Manipulate[
  With[{c = c}, 
    RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 <= c, x < 0}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
      PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
  ],
  {{c, 3.}, 0., 10., 0.1}
]
```

Comment: Perfect. I saw that `With[{c=c}` trick in the documentation while trying to understand the workings of `Manipulate` and `Dynamic` but didn't really think of applying it here. Thank you.